# MySQL server 5.5 on CentOS 6.5 error: "mysqld: unrecognized service"

Tags: linux, installation, centos, mysql

I am using CentOS 6.5. I installed *MySQL Server 5.5* from a `.rpm` package (downloaded from the official MySQL site) using the default `.rpm` installer. I also installed MySQL Client package the same way.

As far as I know, `mysql` process is MySQL *client*, and `mysqld` is MySQL *server* - although I'm not sure.

The problem is that the `mysqld` process is not running. When I type `service mysqld start` or `service mysqld status` I get the same error message

> mysqld: unrecognized service

However, `mysql` process is running fine. I was able to run queries successfully using the `mysql` command.

I need to be repository-independent, so I am not supposed to use `yum`.

When I run `/usr/sbin/mysqld start`, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
>   [ERROR] Aborting
>   [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete

Answer (score 2):

Name of the MySQL service in official rpms provided by MySQL is `mysql`.

So you need to use `service mysql start` to start the MySQL server. The command starts MySQL daemon `mysqld`.

The client program has the same name `mysql`.

In the packages provided by CentOS the service is named `mysqld`.

Comment: How is this helpful?